# How to combine charset of UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 in single PHP email message

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

I am sending emails from PHP via Postfix in different languages. At the end of the message, I put the copyright symbol as below:

```
html_entity_decode('Copyright &#169; '.date('Y').' All rights reserved.');
```

I have two cases now:

When I use the header in the email function as below (**charset=ISO-8859-1**):

```
 $this->headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\r\n";
```

Then, the Arabic content will be received unreadable but the copy right will be received correct.

While when I use the header in the email function as below (**charset=UTF-8**):

```
$this->headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n";
```

Then, the Arabic content is correct but the copyright is shown as black diamond like: �

I am using **Thunderbird** and **Outlook** to read the messages, and both act same.

So my question, how can I have a message with correct Arabic text (or any language other than English) and correct copyright symbol?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use utf8 and simply use the real copyright character

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. I used © instead of &#169; . Please advise another solution. Thanks.

Comment: Use a mailing library like swiftmailer and it just works.

Comment: Actually I don't like to use any library because I have the project is very small. It is the only issue I have with the email.

Comment: An HTML entity *should* never show up as "�", because its encoding is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the content-type HTML it should display the symbols correctly if you the HTML code `&copy;`:

```
$this->headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work out. Also, the text/html will not keep the white spaces. Could you please find something else? Thanks.